# Ошибка "The conditional check failed" при использовании Ansible и Vagrant

Tags: virtualbox, ansible, vagrant

Запускаю команду `vagrant up` в виртуальной машине `VirtualBox` с `Kali Linux` и получаю ошибку: `The conditional check 'ansible_distribution == 'Debian'' failed`

`vagrantfile`:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.base_mac = nil
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.gui = false
    vb.memory = "1024"
    vb.cpus = 1
    vb.linked_clone = true
  end

  N = 3
  (1..N).each do |machine_id|
    config.vm.define "docker-#{machine_id}" do |n|
      n.vm.hostname = "docker-#{machine_id}"
      n.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.56.#{20+machine_id}"
      n.vm.box = "debian/buster64"

      if machine_id == N
        n.vm.provision :ansible do |ansible|
          ansible.limit = "all"
          ansible.playbook = "site.yaml"
          ansible.raw_arguments = [ "-D"]
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Плейбук на ansible:

```
- name: Install Docker into Debian like system
  block:
  - name: install packages
    apt:
      name:
        - apt-transport-https
        - ca-certificates
        - curl
        - gnupg2
        - software-properties-common
      state: present
      update_cache: yes
      cache_valid_time: 3600

  - name: install repo key
    apt_key:
      url: https://download.docker.com/linux/{{ ansible_distribution | lower }}/gpg
      state: present

  - apt_repository:
      repo: deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/{{ ansible_distribution | lower }} {{ ansible_distribution_release }} stable
      state: present

  - name: install docker
    apt:
      name:
        - docker-ce
        - docker-ce-cli
        - containerd.io
      update_cache: yes
      cache_valid_time: 3600
  when: ansible_distribution == 'Debian' or ansible_distribution == 'Ubuntu'

- name: Install Docker into RedHat like system
  block:
    - name: Add Docker repo
      copy:
        src: docker-ce.repo
        dest: /etc/yum.repos.d/docker-ce.repo

    - name: Enable Docker Edge repo
      ini_file:
        dest: /etc/yum.repos.d/docker-ce.repo
        section: 'docker-ce-edge'
        option: enabled
        value: 0

    - name: Install Docker
      yum:
        name: docker-ce
        state: latest
        update_cache: yes
  when: ansible_distribution == 'CentOS' or ansible_distribution == 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux'

- name: put docker config
  copy:
    src: daemon.json
    dest: /etc/docker/daemon.json
  notify: restart docker daemon
```

Фото ошибки после vagrant up
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow! Пожалуйста, не используйте картинки (https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120/551046)

Comment: Если отключали gathering facts, включите обратно

Comment: Нет, я его не отключал, попробовал его вставить, но система ругалась